# Error deploying kivy app on android using buildozer

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

This is the error I am getting after I am trying to convert kivy app to apk using buildozer android debug deploy run command.I have used kivy and kivymd packages and have included both in requirements in buildozer spec file.The version of python is 3.6.10 and kivy is 1.11

These is the full log of the buildozer error.Note here that pip is already installed in my environment but it still says No module named pip

```
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Read available permissions from api-versions.xml
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Run 'dpkg --version'
# Cwd None
Debian 'dpkg' package management program version 1.19.0.5 (amd64).
This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /home/vikas/anaconda3/envs/kivy/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/keytool
# Install platform
# Run 'git config --get remote.origin.url'
# Cwd /home/vikas/Desktop/DataGen/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android.git
# Run 'git branch -vv'
# Cwd /home/vikas/Desktop/DataGen/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
* master 17dfa6a0 [origin/master] Merge pull request #2174 from kivy/release-2020.04.29
# Run '/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install -q  \'appdirs\' \'colorama>=0.3.3\' \'jinja2\' \'six\' \'enum34; python_version<"3.4"\' \'sh>=1.10; sys_platform!="nt"\' \'pep517<0.7.0"\' \'toml\''
# Cwd None
/usr/bin/python3: No module named pip
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pip install -q  'appdirs' 'colorama>=0.3.3' 'jinja2' 'six' 'enum34; python_version<"3.4"' 'sh>=1.10; sys_platform!="nt"' 'pep517<0.7.0"' 'toml'
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     CLUTTER_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
#     CONDA_SHLVL = '2'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     CONDA_EXE = '/home/vikas/anaconda3/bin/conda'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'gnome-'
#     LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
#     OLDPWD = '/home/vikas'
#     GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE = 'ubuntu'
#     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
#     GSETTINGS_SCHEMA_DIR_CONDA_BACKUP = ''
#     USERNAME = 'vikas'
#     CONDA_PREFIX = '/home/vikas/anaconda3/envs/kivy'
#     XDG_VTNR = '2'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
#     MANDATORY_PATH = '/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path'
#     _CE_M = ''
#     XDG_SESSION_ID = '2'
#     USER = 'vikas'
#     CONDA_PREFIX_1 = '/home/vikas/anaconda3'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     QT4_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
#     TEXTDOMAINDIR = '/usr/share/locale/'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN = '/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/06222e6f_6800_4b6d_b51b_c83af8b3ae88'
#     DEFAULTS_PATH = '/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path'
#     PWD = '/home/vikas/Desktop/DataGen'
#     HOME = '/home/vikas'
#     CONDA_PYTHON_EXE = '/home/vikas/anaconda3/bin/python'
#     TEXTDOMAIN = 'im-config'
#     SSH_AGENT_PID = '1545'
#     QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     _CE_CONDA = ''
#     GSETTINGS_SCHEMA_DIR = '/home/vikas/anaconda3/envs/kivy/share/glib-2.0/schemas'
#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu'
#     GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT = 'stderr'
#     CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER = '(kivy) '
#     GTK_MODULES = 'gail:atk-bridge'
#     WINDOWPATH = '2'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     VTE_VERSION = '5202'
#     QT_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
#     XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'
#     IM_CONFIG_PHASE = '2'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu:GNOME'
#     GPG_AGENT_INFO = '/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE = ':1.171'
#     XDG_SEAT = 'seat0'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     GDMSESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = 'this-is-deprecated'
#     LOGNAME = 'vikas'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg'
#     PATH = '/home/vikas/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/vikas/anaconda3/envs/kivy/bin:/home/vikas/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'
#     CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV = 'kivy'
#     GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS = 'JS ERROR;JS LOG'
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/ubuntu:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1449,unix/ubuntu:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1449'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     GTK_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed after I ran sudo apt-get install python3-pip in my ubuntu terminal.